# Installed Ununtu on a server and have 44 terabytes of diskspace but it is only showing 3 terabytes

Tags: disk, disk-management

My Ubuntu installation is not recognising all of the diskspace.
I have 44 Terabytes of disk space, installed RAID 50, and only 2 T of space is showing and useable???

The diskspace is showing up in the bios though

Comment: A bit more details would be helpful. What command did you enter which shows you that only 2TB are useable? Add the output of `parted /dev/<your-44tb-block-device> print`.